# Find the value of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

What is the value of summation $\sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)$ ?

---

Assume $C(n,k)$ implies to choose $K$ items out of $N$ items

Comment: What is $C(2n+1, k)$? is it the choose function?

Comment: If $C(2n+1, k)=\binom{2n+1}{k}$ then the sum evaluates to $4^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use $\binom{2n+1}{k}=\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}$.

> $$2\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\binom{2n+1}{k} + \binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k} = 2^{2n+1}$$

Comment: Just one thing "why multiply by $2$ at start" ?

Comment: @JonGarrick It doesn't matter; you could just as well take everything I wrote and divide it by $2$. I just did it that way because I knew that the sum  $\sum_{k=0}^n$ would be "half" of a full sum $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}$.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. got that !!